# How do I propose my project to be part of Debian too?

Tags: programming, packaging, debian, launchpad, motu

I have a new project hosted at launchpad.net. My project can be useful for both: Ubuntu and Debian. However, I can't find a documentation to start host my project at launchpad.net and get my package mirrored back to Debian.

- How to propose my project to be part of Debian too?
- What is the difference between a Ubuntu and a Debian?
- Can I keep it hosted at launchpad.net but ask it to be cross-hosted (and packaged) at Debian too?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The process for getting a package into Debian is outlined in [this FAQ](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianMentorsFaq). Once your package is in Debian, it will be automatically imported into Ubuntu.

Debian and Ubuntu use the same packaging system. Binary packages (.deb files) for Debian and Ubuntu are not necessarily compatible but when you package for Ubuntu and Debian you upload source code so that it is built for different architectures. Binary packages are built separately for Debian and Ubuntu.

It doesn't matter where you host your code.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need to suggest your package according the the Debian guidelines for [New Packages](http://www.debian.org/doc/developers-reference/pkgs.html#newpackage) where you need to [report a bug](http://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting) that your package be set on the wishlist. Once your package is in Debian it will be mirrored with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

To request packaging in debian you should read [wnpp](http://www.debian.org/devel/wnpp/) page and fill a bug with RFP

Comment: If OP had submitted a package there at time time your answer was written, he or she might still be waiting for action today. It's a graveyard.