# How do I turn my source code into an Ubuntu package and how do I get it in the repositories?

Tags: packaging

I have written a program in C and I wish to create an Ubuntu .deb package. How do I do this? How do I get it included in the Ubuntu official repositories?

Comment: You're asking two separate but obviously related questions. Both have been covered here before. I suggest you take a look at this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16446/how-to-get-my-software-into-ubuntu/16456#16456

Answer (score 4):

This is the best place to start [NewPackages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/NewPackages) it gives you the low down on building and submitting your package. However its not going to happen over night so a short term alternative and something you would need to do at some point any way is set up a launchpad ppa suggested by aking1012 that way you can inform people who would like to use it how to add your ppa and get update of your program and they will be able to give you bug info.

Comment: nice link with NewPackages.  It clarifies the getting into ubuntu procedure, on which I had no idea.  Good 2 know, you should get the check.

Comment: I'm going to guess you probably know more about deb packaging than I do. The first page I found was for a community documentation for 6.10 and thought there might be something more upto date than that.

Answer (score 2):

Debian maintainers guide covers making debs: http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/

getting it included in the repos...think there is a registration/review procedure...anyway, it wouldn't get it into official repos, but launchpad is a start.

launchpad is discussed here: https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA

Answer (score 2):

There are some good packaging answers here:

[What is the simplest Debian Packaging Guide?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345/simplest-debian-packaging-guide)