# How can I get my deb file into the repositories?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, deb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get my software into Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16446/how-to-get-my-software-into-ubuntu)

How can I publish my open-source project in open Ubuntu repositories?

I have already compiled a deb which I can install on all my Ubuntu's but I would like to publish it into the Ubuntu repositories to permit persons to install over `apt-get install` and also to get updates automatically.