# How can I publish a newsletter through the Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center

I have a tech newsletter that I'd like to publish through the USC and I was wondering how to do it?

Comment: Related to [How to get my software into Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16446/how-to-get-my-software-into-ubuntu)

Comment: @nitstorm I think his question is specifically related to newsletters, as in, is there any way to directly publish a newsletter without developing a managing application.

Comment: Hence, I wrote a comment linking to it, and mentioned it's related to it and not an exact duplicate :)

Comment: @nitstorm Good point. =)

Answer (score 3):

http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/

This should get you going...

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like that answer deals with publishing software.  The question asked how to publish a NEWSLETTER, not software.  I, too, would like that question answered.  For example, in Windows, the answer might be MS Publisher.  How about in Ubuntu?  Have I missed something?  Thanks, Fred

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

While it is often used for newsletters, magazines and books, the Ubuntu Software Center is actually designed specifically for software, and does not directly support them.

I've looked into this myself, and it seems that the only way to publish a newsletter/magazine is to write an application that handles the magazine. In other words, you can do either of the following:

1) Create a PDF Viewer that handles your newsletters.

2) You might be able to create a script that automatically loads your newsletter into an existing PDF viewer.

Good luck.

PS: Personally, I would like to see Ubuntu get it's own magazine and book store. Something like "Ubuntu One Bookstore." I don't like how a large percentage of the applications published are magazines, and how they clutter search results.