# How to add the software which i have made to ubuntu's servers

Tags: server, repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get my software into Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16446/how-to-get-my-software-into-ubuntu)

How do I add my software to ubuntu's server so that it is available to others  to install and use it

Answer (score 0):

You will want to check out the developer site on ubuntu.com, as it has all the information you will need to get your software added to the Ubuntu repositories. http://developer.ubuntu.com/

Comment: The information on that site (specifically, http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/) is about how to publish proprietary payware for installation via the Software Center, which may not be what the OP here is looking for.

Comment: Actually that is incorrect. While the process to get software into the Ubuntu repositories used to be using REVU and the MOTU's, that is no longer the case. The new process is to go though the link I provided. If you read the page on the link you provided, you will notice it says "If you are charging for your app, you’ll need to provide details of your Paypal account, a phone number and a postal address. The minimum price you can charge is $2.99.". If you click though and actually go though the process, you will notice that when setting the price, you can click a radio button that says "Free"

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you know if this method supports publishing FOSS apps and making their source available (as in [these methods](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16446/how-to-get-my-software-into-ubuntu))?

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for 
[Personal Package Archive (PPA)](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA). From the help page:

> Using a Personal Package Archive (PPA), you can distribute software and updates directly to Ubuntu users. Create your source package, upload it and Launchpad will build binaries and then host them in your own apt repository.
>
> That means Ubuntu users can install your packages in just the same way they install standard Ubuntu packages and they'll automatically receive updates as and when you make them.

Does that answer your question ?