# Can you publish your app in Software Center via a PPA?

Tags: software-center

I have my free open source desktop app in a PPA. Is it possible to get it in the Software Center so that it is installed from the PPA (so that the user don't need to add my PPA)?

Or should I now use a Click package or what? Changing the packaging from .deb is a bit of a pain.

Comment: possible dupicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/217177/how-does-the-ppa-fit-into-the-scenario-of-publishing-an-application-to-the-ubunt

Comment: This is probably more what you're looking for: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16446/how-to-get-my-software-into-ubuntu

Answer (score -2):

Go to  [myapps portal](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/apps/)  and follow the instructions there.

Comment: your answer doesn't answer the question,  thus not an answer

Comment: Following instructions there is a dead end. Have you actually tried it?