# How can I publish my deb files to custom url?

Tags: apt, application-development, deb

I've seen that some software can be deployed a "deb url" like `deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main`

The "deb url" could be added via:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main"
sudo apt-get update
```

I would like to know how **I can publish my packages to my own domain (or dropbox)**.

Comment: check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/16446/how-to-get-my-software-into-ubuntu

Comment: I have looked at it. While there is a link for ppa,I haven't found a link for a custom repo. `Reprepro` looks like a tool for that purpose but I would need a tutorial for that...

Comment: https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up your own private repository using `reprepro` is not  very hard.

Here are different tutorials:

- [in French](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/tutoriel/comment_creer_depot) on ubuntu-fr.org
- [in English](http://www.tecmint.com/create-deb-pacakge-repository-in-ubuntu/)
- [another one in English](http://blog.jonliv.es/blog/2011/04/26/creating-your-own-signed-apt-repository-and-debian-packages/)