# How to get my software into Ubuntu? (2017)

Tags: apt, ppa, application-submission

I want to get my computational library inside the vanilla Ubuntu distribution. I have already set up a PPA for it, it works, but I want to have it included in the Ubuntu repositories without requiring the PPA.

In the question answered in 2010 ([How to get my software into Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16446/how-to-get-my-software-into-ubuntu)), three solutions are discussed which are not up-to-date anymore, hence an updated answer could be of use. In the 2010 answer we have:

1. The Ubuntu App Developer site which is a `404: Page not found` page as of today at least.
2. The REVU in which it is stated:

   > It is no longer actively used by Ubuntu Developers, so you should generally only submit a package there when a mentor specifically requests you to do so.
3. The  [Application Sponsorship Process](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/NewPackages) which seems probably the right path, but there isn't basically any information there that I can assure is up-to-date. Many references to 2012 such as *"The next MOTU meeting Thursday, December 6th 2012"*, last update to the page itself was in 2015.

Would it be possible for someone to provide some up-to-date information on this, so that nobody else has to look through dead websites?

Comment: The recommended way goes through Debian and the linked pages regarding it seem to be valid. Is this way inapplicable in your case? Why?

Comment: @Melebius have no particular interest in having it anywhere besides Ubuntu. If there's no way to have it directly into Ubuntu, or having it through Debian is the most hassle-free method, please do provide an answer and I'll accept it.