# How to introduce my package for linux users?

Tags: apt, package-management

Recently I created a package named [conolist](https://github.com/E-RROR/conolist) for linux and any system that has a CLI. This package solves a boring problem for terminal geeks, it can help you surf the paths and do some actions on them just in terminal and no writing stuff.

I need help to introduce this package and collect people to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Upload your package to Debian ([howto](https://mentors.debian.net/)).

This gets your package into the Debian Archive and into the Ubuntu Repositories, so it shows up in Ubuntu Software and can be installed by apt. It takes time and patience, but there is a real feeling of accomplishment when YOUR package shows up in a release of Ubuntu.

Some folks will download software from a random github site... but many more won't.

Comment: I think GitHub is a good way of dipping your toes in the water before diving in head first with `apt install`.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix agreed

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get this available to Ubuntu (and other Linux) users is as a snap. As it's python you could follow the `https://snapcraft.io/first-snap#python` guide for turning a python application into a snap. Once built and published in the store, anyone running a supported version of Ubuntu can install it via `snap install conolist` (or whatever you call it).

The `https://askubuntu.com/questions/16446/how-to-get-my-software-into-ubuntu` linked in the comments is a little dated, and doesn't cater to making snaps, which is why I've answered it separately here.

Comment: The website is not working well; it returns to the selection of programming language.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking more how to get people interested in your package.  I would contact sites like omgubuntu.co.uk and others to test your package and tell Linux users if it is good.  These sites usually review programs/apps often and people read them.