# How to add my .deb package to the sudo apt-get install command

Tags: apt, software-installation, sudo

I have a problem. I have a .deb file for my ubuntu app, but I want users to be able to install it using the sudo apt-get install  command. How would I make it so that anyone can install my .deb file with sudo apt-get install?

Comment: What directories does your .deb file install to, most .deb files install to locations that require `sudo` or elevated privileges.  You can package programs to install to $HOME or the user directory that won't require `sudo`, but there will be limitations to this (available only to user who installed it, depending on your UI in use, it may not be seen by all menu systems etc; many of which can be worked around - but the work arounds will be DE more dependent than system directories).

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16446/how-to-get-my-software-into-ubuntu

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Is there a benefit or difference in using dpkg over apt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could read about 'personal package archives' ([PPA](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA)). That's one method to share a debian packaged program with many other users. To install it then they need to do nothing but this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:YOUR-LAUNCHPAD-USERNAME/PPA-NAME 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install SOFTWARE-NAME
```

Those PPAs are hosted on Launchpad so [there website](https://launchpad.net/) might be a good place to start at.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install /path/to/file.deb
```

or, if you are already in the correct directory,

```
sudo apt install ./file.deb
```

Comment: [Odd](https://askubuntu.com/q/40779/349837) I always get _Note, selecting 'on_repo_pkg' instead of './pkg.deb'_. This was added [to `apt` v 1.1](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/blob/e02297b8e22dae04872fe6fab6dba966de65dbba/debian/changelog#L2410)

Comment: @PabloBianchi edited. Thanks for catching that mistake.