# Submit text editor to Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center

I want to place my text editor to Software Center app, like other editors: Scite, Leafpad etc. I have Deb file to install my app. What should I do?

ps. App is freeware PC program, Desktop program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get my software into Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16446/how-to-get-my-software-into-ubuntu)

Answer (score -2):

There is already a great answer to this question [here](
[How to get my software into Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16446/how-to-get-my-software-into-ubuntu)), by @an drewsomething .But i will reproduce it here for the OP.

There are [a number of paths](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/NewPackages) that a package can take to enter Ubuntu. [The overview of Ubuntu development targeted at "upstream" developers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Upstream) like yourself might be a useful place to start, but I'll try to give you some pointers as well.

### Through Debian

Generally, if you are publishing free and open source software [going through Debian first](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13255/how-do-i-propose-my-project-to-be-part-of-debian-too) is the best path. This way ensures that your package will have a dedicated maintainer. It also will reach the largest number of users as it will be available in not just Debian and Ubuntu but all of their derivatives as well. Some useful links for requesting/providing new packages in Debian:

- [Work-Needing and Prospective
  Packages](http://www.debian.org/devel/wnpp/) - Information on how to
  file "Intent to Package" and "Request
  for Package" bugs as well as list of
  open ITPs and RFPs.
- [Debian Mentors
  FAQ](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianMentorsFaq) - debian-mentors is for the
  mentoring of new and prospective
  Debian Developers. It is where you can
  find a sponsor to upload your package to the archive.
- [Debian Developer's Reference](http://www.debian.org/doc/developers-reference/pkgs.html#newpackage) - Debian Developer's Reference's section on new packages. The entire document is invaluable for both Ubuntu and Debian packagers.

### Directly into Ubuntu

In some cases, it might make sense to go [directly into Ubuntu first](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167/how-do-i-put-a-package-into-the-ubuntu-repositories). Some helpful links:

- [The Ubuntu App Developer site](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/) - for lightweight desktop applications, you can submit them directly on the [My Apps](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev) section of developer.ubuntu.com, the [App Review Board](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppReviewBoard) will review them and they will be published in the Software Center.
- [Packaging Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Basic) - an introduction to how to package for Ubuntu.
- [REVU](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU/Packages/REVU) - a web-based tool to which Ubuntu contributors can upload new packages for review by Ubuntu Developers for inclusion into Ubuntu.
- [Sponsorship Process](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SponsorshipProcess) - After entering Ubuntu, you can maintain your package through the sponsorship process.

### Personal Package Archives

Beyond the official Ubuntu and Debian channels, [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) offers you the ability to distribute Debian packages directly to your users through its [Personal Package Archives](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA) or PPAs for short. One particularly useful aspect of a PPA is that you can provide [daily builds](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DailyBuilds) of your software for testing purposes.

Comment: Sorry: not relevant. It is URl about Ubuntu mobile apps? I don't see about ELF programs on PC. I need PC app.

Comment: Edited the link. Please check now.

Comment: I see not relevant url again

Comment: @RProgram  please check out the other question which is linked. There are a lot of useful answers.

Comment: @RProgram please check this. I have edited the answer.